# Fatal error while installing Widget Construction Kit (WCK) for Python

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, clang, x11

I need to install Widget Construction Kit (WCK) for Python. After unpacking the .zip file and parsing "python setup.py install" I get:

```
$ running install 

$running build 

$running build_py 

$running build_ext

$ building '_tk3draw' extension /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing

$ -fno-common -dynamic -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _tk3draw.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/_tk3draw.o In file included from _tk3draw.c:64: /usr/local/include/tk.h:96:13: fatal error: 'X11/Xlib.h' file not found

$ #   include <X11/Xlib.h>

$             ^ 1 error generated. error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1 [Michals-Air-5:~/tkinter3000-1.0-20031212]
```

Any thoughts? I'm running Python 2.7 on OSX.

Comment: Looks like this really dated piece of software wants to run under X11. You can install XQuartz if that’s really what you want, but I would suggest discarding the WCK.

Comment: @deets Thanks. I do have XQuartz installed - is the weird thing. Also, what do you suggest instead of WCK?

Comment: What are you building?

Comment: This: http://effbot.org/media/downloads/tkinter3000-1.1.1-20061204.zip

Comment: I think the question is more what do you want the WCK for. What is your problem you want to solve?

Comment: Ok. This is what is the problem (another question I posted in case I can't get WCK to work): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50205877/python-tkinter-text-widget-extremely-slow-when-adding-multiple-tags-by-tag-add