# Python Tkinter Text widget extremely slow when adding multiple tags by tag_add()

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, textbox, widget

I have a sizeable piece of text contained in a Python Tkinter Text widget. I need to colour the background of each letter in the text, individually, depending on another variable. I do this by adding tags with tag_add. The problem is that the widget responsiveness slows down significantly when all the tags are added. Without the tags everything runs fluently. What can I do?

This is a minimal example of the code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
import Tkinter as ttk
import tkFileDialog
import csv

import ttk
from ttk import *

root = Tk()

root.minsize(width=1280, height=600)
root.maxsize(width=1280, height=600)

w, h = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
x = (w/2) - 640
y = (h/2) - 300
root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (1200, 640, x, y-80))

#Horizontal (x) Scroll bar
xscrollbar = Scrollbar(orient=HORIZONTAL)
xscrollbar.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
#Vertical (y) Scroll Bar
yscrollbar = Scrollbar()
yscrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

MSA_text1 = Text(height=30, width=150, xscrollcommand=xscrollbar.set, yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set)
MSA_text1.pack()
MSA_text1.configure(wrap="none", font="TkFixedFont")
MSA_text1.place(x=105,y=0)

#Configure the scrollbars
xscrollbar.config(command=MSA_text1.xview)
yscrollbar.config(command=MSA_text1.yview)


for number2 in range(1,20):

    MSA_text1.insert(END, "SPAELHSFTHCGQTALTLQGATTTEASNILRSCHACRGGNPQHQMPRGHIRRGLLPNHIWQGDITHFKYKNTLYRLHVWVDTFSGAISATQKRKETSSEAISSLLQAIAHLGKPSYINTDNGPAYISQDFLNMCTSLAIRHTTHVPYNPTSSGLVERSNGILKTLLYKYFTDKPDLPMDNALSIALWTINHLNVLTNCHKTRWQLHHSPRLQPIPETRSLSNKQTHWYYFKLPGLNSRQWKGPQEALQEAAGAALIPVSASSAQWIPWRLLKRAACPRPVGGPADPKEKDLQHHG" +"\n")

    for number in range(0,295):

        MSA_text1.tag_add(number, str(number2)+"."+str(number), str(number2)+"."+str(number+1))
        MSA_text1.tag_config(number, background="red", foreground="black")

MSA_text1.configure(state="disabled")

mainloop()
```

Comment: Please try to provide a [mcve] that illustrates the problem. It's hard to tell from your question if you're talking about hundreds of tags or millions of tags, and one long line of text or hundreds of thousands of lines of text.

Comment: @ Bryan Oakley Thank you, that is a fair point. I edited my post to now include an example.